# how to check if data exist in mysql database before enter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

`Table 1` is loaded with data as seen below, there is `TABLE 2` which is empty but contain same structure as `TABLE1` my problem is if i want to insert data in`TABLE 2` i want to to check first in `TABLE 1` if records to be entered in `TABLE 2` have same name as `NAME` column from `TABLE 1` if `NAME` are not same data should be ignored and not entered into database.

```
 TABLE 1
 ST_ID   NAME          MATHS   GEOGRAPHY   ENGLISH
  1001   Alan Wegman    80       85          70
  1002   Robert Franko  79       65          60
  1003   Francis John   90       75          67
  1004   Finn Harry     88       87          93


  TABLE 2
  ST2_ID   NAME   MATHS   GEOGRAPHY   ENGLISH   ST_ID
```

These are my codes so far, even if there is alternative way of doing what i want i will appreciate if you share with me.

```
`$query="insert into student_info (NAME, MATHS, GEOGRAPHY, ENGLISH)  VALUES ('$name','$maths','$geog','$english')";


 if (mysql_query($query))
 {
   echo "<b>";
   echo "<h3>";
   echo "RECORD ADDED ";
   echo "<h3>";
   echo "</b>";
 }
   else
 {
 echo "<b>";
 echo "<h3>";
 echo "RECORD NOT ENTERED SOMETHING WENT WRONG";
 echo "</h3>";
 echo "</b>";
 echo "<br>";
 echo mysql_error();
  }
 ?>
```

`

NOTE:ST2_ID is auto increment

I need your thought guys.

Comment: try to select record from table2 where name  & then check for rowcount if its 0 then insert else record is present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily you can make it in PHP, first, you do a query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE name = '$name'
```

Then:

```
if(mysql_num_rows($queryExecuted) > 0) { /* insert to table 2 */}
```

We check if the query had return at least one row (where `$queryExecuted` is the return object of the `SELECT`)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the `$name` variable, you can simply query table 1 with a select statement to find if information for a specific student exists in table 1 (`SELECT * from table1 WHERE NAME=$name`). If this query returns any results, perform the insertion into table 2 which you mention above. Otherwise, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this in your SQL by adding a WHERE condition on your insert statement.  Perhaps something like this:

```
 insert into student_info (
                           NAME
                         , MATHS
                         , GEOGRAPHY
                         , ENGLISH
                           ) 
 VALUES ('$name'
        ,'$maths'
        ,'$geog'
        ,'$english')"
 WHERE NOT EXIST (select *
                  from table2
                  where name = '$name');
```